# Complex if else logic

Tags: c#, logic

Friends

How do I implement following complex logic?

flag1 can be "N" or "A" or "I"
flag2 can be "N" or "A" or "I"
flag3 can be "N" or "A" or "I"

function (string flag1, string flag2, string flag3)
begin

The function needs to return:

1. return "None" if flag1, flag2 and flag3 are "N"
2. else return "Active" if flag1, flag2 and flag3 are "A"
3. else return "Inactive" if flag1, flag2 and flag3 are "I"
4. else return "both" if flag1, flag2 and flag3 are either "A" AND "I" (OR "N")

e.g. 1) flag1 is "A" and flag2 is "I" and flag3 is "I"
e.g. 2) flag1 is "I" and flag2 is "A" and flag3 is "I"
e.g. 2) flag1 is "A" and flag2 is "N" and flag3 is "I"

retrun result

end

Thanks for reply but none of post gives answer. I know if else constrauct and looking for logic to implement above psedocode. All four are possibel conditions specially #4 is complex and need to know how to implement that.

Comment: Are you actually asking how to compose the boolean logic?  Or are you looking for an alternative to doing so?

Comment: @Kumar: do you want us to translate your pseudo-code to C#, which will be almost straightforward?

Comment: How should we read point 4? Those parens make no sense now.

Comment: What should the function return if none of the conditions match? And could expand on what you want 4. to do?

Comment: This is in dire need of a "truth table."  Or don't they teach those any more?

Comment: Your examples do not make sense. Please provide a table of flag1, flag2, flag3, and the expected return value, for all the possible input values.

Comment: Because Kumar is doing a bad job of explaining it, I'll throw in my hand: If all are same, return the unanimous value, if any or all do not match, return "Both".

Comment if that's wrong Kumar

Answer (score 20, accepted):

Your logic for point 4 is confusing...

I would use an enum value for this, rather than strings - it is much more type-safe (eg what if someone passed `"WIBBLEWOBBLE"` to your method? What should it return?)

```
enum Value { None, Active, Inactive, Both }

private Value GetValue(Value flag1, Value flag2, Value flag3) {
    if (flag1 == flag2 && flag2 == flag3)    // they are all the same
        return flag1;
    else return Value.Both;    // there is a difference
}
```

Comment: get rid of the else, you already returned if the if was true. Otherwise +1 for being able to figure out the arcane requirements posted.. Assuming your intepretation is accurate..

Comment: Ay, the `else` is superfluous, but it does make it obvious what the logic is

Comment: As a note, the `enum` makes this more type safe but it would still be possible to send in invalid inputs.  You can cast any integral value to a particular `enum` type.  (I would have suggested the `enum` as well.  I just don't want people getting a false sense of security.)

Comment: 4.else return "both" if flag1, flag2 and flag3 are either "A" AND "I" (OR "N")
-- actually I am looking implementation for this logic. It means both "A" and "I" must be there in flag1, flag2 and flag3 and remaning flag can be "N" or can be "A" and "I". please see my examples for #4

Comment: Hopefully he will flip this from me to you.  I tried to delete my answer but it won't let me because it's accepted.

Answer (score 2):

```
[Flags]
enum SomeWierdReturn
{ Both = 0, None = 1, Active = 2, Inactive = 4 }

public SomeWierdReturn DoSomething(SomeWierdReturn flag1, SomeWierdReturn flag2, SomeWierdReturn flag3)
{
    return (SomeWierdReturn)(flag1 & flag2 & flag3);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think it serves both readability and speed if you first check if all 3 values are equal.

```
if ((flag1 == flag2) and (flag1 == flag3))
   // use a switch or table to go 'I' -> Inactive etc
else
  return "Both"; // as far as i understood 4)
```

Answer (score 0):

This would* work. Can't say I like it.

```
 string key = flag1 + flag2 + flag3;
 switch(key){
     case "NNN":
         return "None";
      case "AAA":
        return "Active";
      case "III":
        return "Inactive";
      default:
        break;
  }
  // ;)
 //Trying to make it as confusing as your requirement #4
  var four = (
     from s in key
     select s
   ).Distinct();

  if(four.Count() > 1){
    return "Both";
  }



 }
```

Comment: You justified the bad code, there's no reason you should be voted down here.

Answer (score 0):

Robaticus gave you the right answer but in a comment rather than a post so I will expand upon it.

We have three flags that can take each of three states.  There are thus 3 * 3 * 3 = 27 possible options.

When facing complex if..then logic and such a small address space it makes no sense at all to try to code all the if..then's.  Instead, one three-dimensional array holding a total of 27 elements.

const int None = 0;
const int Inactive = 1;
const int Active = 2;

private int ParseFlag(string Flag)
{
    switch (Flag)
    {
        case "N": return None;
        case "I": return Inactive;
        case "A": return Active;
        default throw new Exception(string.Format("Got a flag value of {0} but expected N, I or A", Flag));
    }
}

public FlagResult Lookup(string Flag1, string Flag2, string Flag3)
{
     return FlagData[ParseFlag(Flag1), ParseFlag(Flag2), ParseFlag(Flag3)];
}

I'll let you build the array.